# MySQL password won't update

Tags: mysql, change-password, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to reset my MySQL-password, using whatever I found on Google, however it fails systematically. These are the three thing I tried:

```
$ read -s password
$ echo ${#password}
10

$ echo "use mysql; update user set authentication_string=password('$password') where user='root';" | sudo mysql -uroot
$ echo "use mysql; select authentication_string from user where user='root';"  | sudo mysql -uroot
authentication_string
*B69D82770841AB22761D61C3C7DED4FBE78D99C7
$ mysql -uroot "-p$password"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

$ sudo mysqladmin -u root password "$password"
mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Warning: Since password will be sent to server in plain text, use ssl connection to ensure password safety.
$ mysql -uroot "-p$password"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

$ echo "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('$password');" | sudo mysql -uroot
$ mysql -uroot "-p$password"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I also tried all three with `echo "flush privileges" | sudo mysql -uroot` between updating and testing, but still `Access denied`.

This is my mysql version

```
$ sudo mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Why does updating my password have no affect in these three ways?

**EDIT**

I also tried (since I am using >=5.7.6):

```
$ echo "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$password';"  | sudo mysql -uroot
$ echo "flush privileges; "  | sudo mysql -uroot
$ mysql -uroot "-p$password"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

**EDIT 2**

I also tried, as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html :

```
$ echo "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$password';" > changepw.sql
$ chmod 777 changepw.sql 
$ sudo service mysql stop
$ sudo mysqld --init-file=`pwd`/changepw.sql &
$ sudo service mysql restart
$ mysql -uroot "-p$password"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Comment: If you down-vote, thank you for your feedback, but please motivate in a comment. Otherwise it's quite useless.

Comment: Check your authentication method (`select user, host, plugin from user`), it might not be using a password so changing the password (without setting the plugin) wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out something similar. Would you know where MySQL documents this?

Comment: This is something preset by the ubuntu installer/repository/package, not particularly by MySQL; MariaDB mentions it in their faq, see e.g. [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/differences-in-mariadb-in-debian-and-ubuntu/); not sure where it's officially documented fro MySQL though.

Comment: This is the second time this happened to me, and the last time I simply accepted life without mysql. I am happy I have this documented now, and don't see why this is an unfair question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to make sure the `mysql_native_password` plugin was used, afterwards `ALTER USER` works.

```
$ read -s password
$ echo ${#password}

$ echo "use mysql; update user set plugin='mysql_native_password'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$password'; " | sudo mysql -uroot -p
```

I could not find any mention of `ALTER USER` not working being the default behavior here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Nor any mention about plugins, nor could I figure out whether this is something Ubunt 18-specific. So I am skeptical about how adequate this solution is, but for me it worked.

Comment: finally I did it :)